# Icon font link icons are untappable on iphone

Tags: html, css, fonts, icons

I have used some fontello icon fonts for the social media icons in the header of a site I designed.
These work great on desktop and display fine on all platforms I've tested. However the link functionality of them seems to not work in mobile browsers on my iphone (you can click them fine on a desktop with a mobile-width viewport).

Any idea why these are tappable and how to fix?

A page in question: http://sergedenimes.com/contact-us/
The icons are top-right in the header in full-view and top left in mobile.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and have hoped someone had answered you on here. In the end I found a silly `display: inline-block;` in the `<a>` tag, solves this problem.

Found on: http://css-tricks.com/html-for-icon-font-usage/